# PHP Smarty Tags isset referer Session

Tags: php, session, smarty

i can't figure out what i am missing. 
My Plan: If the customer come from the Homepage with Products, it shall save the Link and the customer shall be able to get back to that point.

if the customer opens Link directly, he shall see a Link to the mainpage.

```
{php}
$go_back = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
{/php}
{if $go_back|strpos:"https://kundencenter.example.org" === false}

$_SESSION['refererURL'] = $go_back;

{elseif isset($smarty.session.refererURL)}
<li id='Primary_Navbar-Account'><a href='".$_SESSION[refererURL]."'><i class='fa fa-home'></i> Homepage</a></li>
{else}
<li id='Primary_Navbar-Account'><a href='https://example.org'><i class='fa fa-home'></i> Homepage</a></li>
{/if}
```

Comment: {elseif $smarty.session.refererURL} This condition is enough to check the session is set or not in smarty

Comment: okay thank you but this seems still not to work. :-S

Comment: Sorry, If I'm misunderstood. As soon as you assign value to session close the existing if condition and option new if condition to check session value is set or not.

Comment: {php}
$go_back = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
{/php}

{if $go_back|strpos:"https://kundencenter.eXAMPLE.com" === false}

$_SESSION['refererURL'] = $go_back;

{/if}
{if isset($smarty.session.refererURL)}
<li id='Primary_Navbar-Account'><a href='".$_SESSION[refererURL]."'><i class='fa fa-home'></i> Homepage</a></li>
{else}
<li id='Primary_Navbar-Account'><a href='https://example.com'><i class='fa fa-home'></i> Homepage</a></li>
{/if}

doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: Could you kindly take my code and make an example?

Comment: Now can you please try my first comment? and may I know in other pages session is working fine?

Comment: i tried both. Your first command and your second, then i tried 20 different things and then i wrote again..